# Update table row every minute using with Cron Job

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, cron

I am trying to update table row every minute when crondate(timestamp field) and current timestamp match. When both match i am setting state = 0 but not working. I have check cronjob and it is working and executing every miniute.

I will thankful If anyone can help me.

My Code:

```
function runCronJob(){  
    $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $update_query = "UPDATE #__cronjob_run SET state=0 WHERE crondate = '$timestamp'";
    $db->setQuery($update_query);
    $db->query();

}
```

[image: Mt Table]

Comment: that's really the table name ? **#__cronjob_run** and `crondate = NOW()` would be more efficent

Comment: @Dagon In Joomla we have to write table name with #__cronjob_run.

Comment: Are you certain your date formats are matching on both sides of the where clause? This is a frequent source of headaches. Not sure what DBms youre using here.

Comment: This also looks like it needs matching down to the second. Try logging your contents of $update_queries to a file after executing them and see what it is actually doing.

Comment: Check that the MySQL server, the server the PHP code is running on and the timezone in the php.ini file have the same timezone as a TIMESTAMP field takes that into account.

Comment: Look at the generated query in the debugger.  I think your quoting is wrong.   I suspect you want $timestamp to be treated as a variable and  that means you need to  concatenate it with the rest of the string using php.   So probably   '" . $timesstamp . "'      or something along those lines.

Comment: Relying on an exact timestamp does not look right to me. 
Do you want to describe what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as to why you need to compare the dates, so I'll just assume you want to update rows that where created that exact second.

I believe it will be much easier for you to use [MySql Events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) as you won't have to worry about timezones as it's the same time, and basically it runs a cron itself and you have basically the same options.

another plus that it will be faster to run as no need for PHP to run.

Since I see you're using PHPMyAdmin, go to your database -> Events -> Add Event and from there it's pretty straight forward.

That will make your query something like :

`UPDATE #__cronjob_run SET state=0 WHERE crondate = now()`